# Partial indexing in sphinx

Tags: php, sphinx

I have implemented sphinx to search the words and it's working fine. Currently i am creating indexes of all records present in table using

```
$ sudo /usr/local/bin/searchd --config /usr/local/etc/sphinx.conf
```

But, now i want to create partial indexes i.e indexing should happen only for newly added records in table and old indexes should also persist.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to add new entries into plain indexes in Sphinx. You can only [update attributes](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#api-func-updateatttributes) on them or use so-called [delta indexing scheme](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#delta-updates).

Another approach is using [real-time indexes](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#rt-indexes) which can be updated using SphinxQL queries.